# Why doesn't my front Audio jack work?

Tags: audio

Neither the mic nor the audio jack on my front PC work. It is a centurion case that I purchased from newegg. I also correctly verified that the cables are pluged into the mother board correctly. Anyone have seen this type of problem...?

Other details: Asus Mobo, onboard audio. Windows7. The same problem persisted when XP was on this machine.

**Update:** It doesn't seem to work on Linux either

Comment: Exactly what model Asus motherboard do you have?

Comment: asus m2npv-vm (a micro atx mobo)

Answer (score 3):

In cases like this, I first suspect a driver issue. Update the chipset drivers for your motherboard. You should be able to find them by going to the manufacturer's support website. Another possible solution would be a BIOS update.

However, it's also possible that it's faulty hardware. If the chipset and BIOS updates don't work, RMA the motherboard and try a new one.

Comment: There are no chipset updates. ASUS has pretty bad driver support for their "ASUS M2NPV-VM AM2 NVIDIA GeForce 6150 Micro ATX AMD Motherboard"

Comment: And there is no hope finding chipset drivers on nvidia's website :/

Comment: That's poor form on Asus's part. I guess you know 1) Which manufacturer not to use next time, and 2) What questions to ask before you commit to a motherboard. Boo, Asus.

Answer (score 3):

In the BIOS, look for a setting called '**Front panel audio**'.  Is it set to **HD audio**?  Try changing it to **AC97** instead.

Comment: I don't see this option :(